# Accessing a child node using JSON within PHP and file_get_contents()

Tags: php, json, file-get-contents

OK I am stumped.

I have tried numerous different approaches and I've spent the best part of a good few hours searching to no avail to my exact situation, that or I am tired and blind.

Here is the raw json pulled from a URI using file_get_contents():

```
{"id":"XXX","name":"Customer1","os":"CentOS Linux 7.3.1611 Core","cpu_type":"Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E3-1245 V2 @ 3.40GHz","networking_v4":[{"addr":"xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx","if":"eth0"}],"networking_v6":[{"addr":"xxxx","if":"eth0"},{"addr":"xxxx","if":"eth0"}],"agent_version":0.96,"status":"up","last_update":1505949230,"first_update":1500588943,"notifications_count":8,"ip_whois":{"ip":"xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx","hostname":"xxx","city":"Garwood","region":"New Jersey","country":"US","loc":"xxx","org":"AS20473 Choopa, LLC","postal":"xxx"},"additional_fields":[{"value":"xxx","key":"Datacenter"},{"value":"","key":""},{"value":"","key":""},{"value":"","key":""},{"value":"","key":""},{"value":"","key":""},{"value":"","key":""},{"value":"","key":""},{"value":"","key":""}]}
```

As you can see its a pretty simple request and I have every bit of data except those nested within networking_v4 and networking_v6.

I tried to access those like so:

```
'ipv4' => $json->networking_v4->addr,
'ipv4dev' => $json->networking_v4->if,
'ipv6' => $json->networking_v6->addr,
'ipv6dev' => $json->networking_v6->if,
```

Here is the full snapshot of code in its entirety:

```
  $content = file_get_contents($url);
  $json = json_decode($content);
  $server_lastupd = $json->last_update;
  $server_firstupd = $json->first_update;
  $server = array(
    'id' => $json->id,
    'name' => $json->name,
    'os' => $json->os,
    'cputype' => $json->cpu_type,
    'ipv4' => $json->networking_v4->addr,
    'ipv4dev' => $json->networking_v4->if,
    'ipv6' => $json->networking_v6->addr,
    'ipv6dev' => $json->networking_v6->if,
    'status' => $json->status,
    'lastupd' => $json->$server_lastupd,
    'firstupd' => $json->$server_firstupd,
    'notifications' => $json->notifications_count,
    'ip' => $json->ip_whois->ip,
    'hostname' => $json->ip_whois->hostname,
    'city' => $json->ip_whois->city,
    'region' => $json->ip_whois->region,
    'country' => $json->ip_whois->country,
    'loc' => $json->ip_whois->loc,
    'org' => $json->ip_whois->org,
    'postal' => $json->ip_whois->postal,
    'dctag' => $json->additonal_fields->dctag,
    'source' => "XXX"
  );
  return $server;
```

So my issue is I appear to be unable to access the child content within networking_v4 and networking_v6.

Any help on this would be massively appreciated, its stumped me for the best part of 6 hours last night and a few more today, so I give in, someone please show me the light!
Many thanks :)

Comment: see those brackets in the json ? `[]` ? these are arrays, not objects.

Comment: In the future look at `var_dump($json)` or `print_r($json)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like those are nested in arrays from the [{"key':"value"},{"key":"value"}] square brackets. have you tried

```
ipv4 => $json->networking_v4[0]->addr,
```

Comment: This did the trick!
Cannot believe it was that simple, something to remember in future. Yes they are nested arrays or child arrays to some people, however, I couldn't quite figure out how to access them, I tried it the other way forgetting this method, nevermind it works and your answer is very much appreciated. many thanks :)

Comment: Also noticed my own spelling mistake further down! :D thanks again @reginol_Blindhop

Answer (score 0):

Try `$json->networking_v4[0]->addr`.

Both the `networking_v4` and the `networking_v6` keys point to arrays, so you need to pick which index you want to look at. The former only has one element, so it's easy to pick index `0`, but the latter has multiple elements, so you'll need to figure out which one you want.